# Manipulate url rewriting and history with javascript and php in order to display or load the right view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I have a main layout in my Symfony2.6 application. It's a twig view with HTML5 tags and standards.

I extend the layout like this in other view (all twig view start with this code) : `{% extends "MySpaceMyBundle::layout.html.twig" %}`

In the `layout.html.twig` I have a `{% block content %}` which allow me to create the other view|templates in order to extend the main layout.

But in a view I have a select drop down, where all values display a different form according to the choice made.

This is an example:

```
{% extends "MySpaceMyBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

  {% block content %}
    <select class="form-control" id="selectCategory">
      <option selected disabled>choose your type</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addCategory1') }}"> Category 1</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addCategory2') }}"> Category 2</option>
      <option value="{{ path('addCategory3') }}"> Category 3</option>
    </select>

    <div id="displayForm"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //load a template/page with javascript in the div
      $('#selectCategory').change(function() {
        var url = $(this).val();
        $.get(url , {} , function(showForm) {
          $("#displayForm").html(showForm);
        })
      });
    </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

As you can see, my javascript allow me to charge in the right div the rest of the form. For now it works well.

See the code for category1 form:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}

  <form action="{{ path('addCategory1_process') }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <div>
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-small btn-success"/>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Rewrite url properly, here for category1, so whith this script 
    //the url is localhost/MyProject/addCategories/Category1
    window.history.pushState("", "My Title", "{{ path('ajouterCategory1') }}");
  </script>
```

So when I make a choice in my dropdown in order to **display** the right form, it works well, and the url is the right one. So it's good. 
But if I want **to go back in the history browser**, the same page appear even if the **url is the good one**.

***Example:***

> when I display the page with the url
>   `localhost/MyProject/addCategories`, I have the select tag for making a
>   choice.  I make a choice for **category1**, so in my div the form is
>   displaying well and I have my **right url** which is
>   `localhost/MyProject/addCategories/Category1`. But when I go back, on
>   **the previous page with my browser**, I have well the url
>   `localhost/MyProject/addCategories` but the page displaying is always
>   `localhost/MyProject/addCategories/Category1`.

Someone know how can I proceed to **manage the history** Event with Javascript for having the right url for the right view when I go back or forward?

The other point that is I want the user don't access to the page with url `localhost/MyProject/addCategories/Category1` in rewriting her **manually** in the browser bar. The user could access to the page `localhost/MyProject/addCategories/Category1` only just by make a choice in the select on page `localhost/MyProject/addCategories` . **I would like to make a 404 error in php with Symfony** if users try to put this url manually in the browser bar.

Comment: You may need to use pushState() or something. Look at this for further understanding: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

But I noticed ( even on big sites ) that this does problems. I got this behaviour on many sites, that when I click "Back" in my browser, the url changes, but the content doesn't.

Comment: @JLow I once was able to fix this behaviour for my site. I need to check it, maybe I can provide some details.

Comment: @JLow that's why I sear a solution because I watch this behavior on many sites too. You go back with the browser, the url changed but not the content. Thank you in advance for checking on your website.